# How to make dynamic router base in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```
export default {
  router: {
    base: routeBase
  },
}
```

when I use lang = french, it will be changed to /french/language as base URL
when I use button to change the language as lang = english, it will be changed to /english/language base URL

Comment: See https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamic-base-in-vue-router/1026

Comment: You should use [i18n module](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/)

Comment: @bmartins actually when I try to set router base as '/', I've set /{lang}/language in my Nginx as baseURL, so I have to set my project router base as '/{eng or fr}/language'. i18n module will add the existing path to be /lang/language/fr or eng, not change the base URL it self.

Comment: @LeliantoPradana do you solve this yet ?
I used middleware to change app.router.history.base but it got bug while refresh the page